# auto generate pyqt4 table

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
import sys
names= ['Patrick', 'Kyle', 'John', 'Martin', 'Frank', 'Paul', 'Sarah', 
'Josh', 'Cian', 'Eamonn'] 
mylist = [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9  , 10 ]
def main():  

    app     = QApplication(sys.argv)
    table   = QTableWidget()
    tableItem   = QTableWidgetItem()

    # initiate table
    table.setWindowTitle("QTableWidget Example @pythonspot.com")
    table.resize(400, 250)
    table.setRowCount(4)
    table.setColumnCount(2) 

    #table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString("Names;Number;").split(";"))
    #table.setVerticalHeaderLabels(QString("L1;L2;L3;L4").split(";"))

    # set data
    table.setItem(0,0, QTableWidgetItem(names[0]))
    table.setItem(0,1, QTableWidgetItem(str(mylist[0])))
    table.setItem(1,0, QTableWidgetItem(names[1]))
    table.setItem(1,1, QTableWidgetItem(str(mylist[1])))
    table.setItem(2,0, QTableWidgetItem(names[2]))
    table.setItem(2,1, QTableWidgetItem(str(mylist[2])))
    table.setItem(3,0, QTableWidgetItem(names[3]))
    table.setItem(3,1, QTableWidgetItem(str(mylist[3])))

    # show table
    table.show()
    return app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

This is my code it creates the following output.

screenshot of output

[image]

Does anybody know how i could use a for loop to add each element of the two lists to the pyqt4 table. Some of the lists I use could be very large and i dont want to add each element of the list individually .

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need `mylist` which is a list with following numbers. You could use `zip` on `names` and `list(range(len(names)))` or better: loop using `enumerate`, starting at 1:

```
for i,name in enumerate(names,1):
    table.setItem(i,0, QTableWidgetItem(name))
    table.setItem(i,1, QTableWidgetItem(str(i)))
```

if you need to put something else than indices (ex: phone numbers as you stated), you could try this approach:

```
for phone_number,name in zip(mylist,names):
    table.setItem(i,0, QTableWidgetItem(name))
    table.setItem(i,1, QTableWidgetItem(str(phone_number)))
```

Note that `phone_number` as a number cannot start by `0`, so maybe it's not a very good example for a list of integers.

Also note that `zip` stops on the shortest list.

Comment: ok that looks good thanks. my list was just an example list, it really contains phone numbers. Didntn want to be posting them here :)

Comment: you could have put imaginary phone numbers. That would have avoided my to post the `enumerate` solution. See my edit.